# Has Greencard but got B2 Stamping at entry

Tags: usa

My Mom is a US greencard holder (expires in 2025). I noticed in her most recent US entry stamping on her passport that she has been marked as B2 (with 6 month validity). is there a problem?

Comment: Did she actually enter with her green card?

Comment: Was she traveling with a Canadian passport?

Comment: She entered with Greencard. She doesnt have any other Visa. And she has Indian passport.